# Linking Python Files Assistance

Tags: python

I understand how to actually link python files, however, i don't understand how to get variable's from these linked files. I've tried to grab them and I keep getting NameError.

How do I go about doing this? The reason i want to link files is to simply neaten up my script and not make it 10000000000 lines long. Also, in the imported python script, do i have to import everything again? Another question, do i use the self function when using another scripts functions?

ie;

Main Script:

```
import sys, os
import importedpyfile
```

Imported Py File

```
import sys, os
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand how to actually link python files, however, i don't
>   understand how to get variable's from these linked files. I've tried
>   to grab them and I keep getting NameError.

How are you doing that? Post more code. For instance, the following works:

file1.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from file2 import file2_func, file2_variable

file2_func()
print file2_variable
```

file2.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

file2_variable = "I'm a variable!"

def file2_func():
    print "Hello World!"
```

> Also, in the imported python script, do i have to import everything
>   again?

Nope, modules should be imported when the python interpreter reads that file.

> Another question, do i use the self function when using another
>   scripts functions?

Nope, that's usually to access class members. See [python self explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained).

There is also more than one way to import files. See the other answer for some explanations.

Comment: Thankyou. Such a simple answer and what i was looking for ^_^

Comment: What do you mean? If you call a function defined in another file, when that function returns or otherwise exits, control will pass back to the calling function in the original file.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are trying to ask is how to get access to global vars from on .py file without having to deal with namespaces.

In your main script, replace the call to `import importedpyfile` to say this instead

```
from importedpyfile import *
```

Ideally, you keep the code the way you have it.  But instead, just reference those global vars with the importedpyfile namespace.

e.g.

```
import importedpyfile
importedpyfile.MyFunction()  # calls "MyFunction" that is defined in importedpyfile.py
```

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - Care to explain? You may not "like" the answer, but it will likely satisfy the OP's question.  I was about to append a paragraph about accessing vars from namespaces, but haters gonna hate.

Comment: For one thing, wildcard imports overwrite. Thus, if you import from `foo.py` and `bar.py` in that order, and they both have global vars names `baz`, then `foo.baz` will be overwritten by `bar.baz`

Comment: Geez... ok, I updated the answer to suggest keeping with namespaces.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14277629/20862 http://stackoverflow.com/q/4495469/20862

Comment: Thankyou, and i realised my question was rather stupid and i should have just tried other ways myself and figured it out myself. Sorry for the stupid question. :C

Answer (score 1):

Python modules are not "linked" in the sense of C/C++ linking libraries into an executable. A Python **import** operation creates a name that refers to the imported module; without this name there is no (direct) way to access another module.